# Why does XCode show launch image warnings?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I get the following warnings in my iPad launch images, but not the iPhone images:

[image: launch images ipad]

I can't find the text related to the warnings anywhere.

Here are my plist settings:

[image: plist ipad images]

And my image files:

[image: image file names]

When I tried "Default-iPad.png" it didn't fix it either.

The image dimensions are 768 x 1024 (portrait) and 1024 x 768 (landscape).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make your mouse cursor hover over the warning sign and the warning should appear.

It'll tell you that iPad Launch Images should be 768 x 1004 and 1024 x 748
That means you have to remove the status bar from the image.

Comment: If your artwork is off by 20px then you can most likely make this warning go away by hiding the status bar initially on application launch. You can do this by setting the following build setting to YES: "Status bar is initially hidden" (i.e. UIStatusBarHidden)

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but it must be a mistake because if you look at the documentation _from_ Apple it says it wants a 768x1004 and 1024x748 image but xcode is telling me it wants 768x1024 and 1024x768. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: As Shizam noted, this appears to be in conflict with the Apple documentation. However, removing the top 20 (or 40 for Retina) pixels resolves the issue. On the iPhone, the status bar is "covered" by the iOS, and no warning about "wrong" image sizes is displayed.

Comment: I had the same issue. My problem was that I had an old Default.png and Default-Portrait~ipad.png in my supporting files section that XCode was reading first. So no matter how many times I updated the Ipad one, it ignored it. I deleted the dupe files and everything is good now.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's the deal for launch images which work for all iPads.**  This should tell you exactly what to do and what you need. You need four images, either the first group or the second one, depending on if your app is set to show the top status bar or not.  Notice that the names are the same whether your image has room for the status bar or not.

***Description : image width x height - image name***

---

### iPad - with status bar turned ON (shows wifi connection, time, etc)

Portrait : 768x1004 - Default-Portrait.png

Landscape : 1024x748 - Default-Landscape.png

Portrait Retina : 1536x2008 - Default-Portrait@2x.png

Landscape Retina : 2048x1496 - Default-Landscape@2x.png

---

### iPad - with status bar turned OFF (more screen real estate)

Portrait : 768x1024 - Default-Portrait.png

Landscape : 1024x768 - Default-Landscape.png

Portrait Retina : 1536x2048 - Default-Portrait@2x.png

Landscape Retina : 2048x1536 - Default-Landscape@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

You can either resize your images to be 20px smaller in height, or you can make the status bar hide during app launch.

In new versions of XCode (I use 4.5.2), there is a checkbox to hide the status bar in the `Project > Target > Summary` settings, right above the launch image previews:

[image]

Comment: If you do that, you have to make sure to re-display the status bar in your app. For me, it disappeared completely after checking the box as suggested.